# Add more than one label in ModelChoiceField - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this kind of model:

```
class Cities(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_city_name(self):
        if self.sub_species:
            return str(self.country) + " " + str(self.city)
```

With this data by example in my model:

```
France Paris
France Lyon
France Marseille
Germany Berlin
Germany Bonn
```

## views.py

```
filter_drop_down_menu_city = CityNameForm()
```

## forms.py

```
class CityNameChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """
    CityNameChoiceField Class
    """

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        """
        This function return the label of the instance
        :param obj:
        :return:
        """
        return obj.get_city_name()


class CityNameForm(forms.Form):
    """
    CityNameForm Class
    """
    cityName = CityNameChoiceField(
        queryset=Cities.objects.order_by('country', 'city'),
        empty_label="(ALL Cities)",
        help_text="",
        required=False,
        label='Cities',
    )
```

In my template my choice field render the list of cities listed before.

But i want that kind of choice render:

```
France
France Paris
France Lyon
France Marseille
Germany
Germany Berlin
Germany Bonn
```

The user can choice a country too (and after i can make the city selection)

Comment: add your template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier way to achieve what you want simply by structuring choices following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices). Good luck :)

```
def cities_as_choices():
    choices = []
    for country in models.Cities.objects.values('country').distinct():
        new_country = []
        cities = []
        new_country.append(country.get('country'))

        for city in models.Cities.objects.filter(country=country.get('country')):
            cities.append([city.pk, city.city])

        new_country.append(cities)
        choices.append(new_country)

    return choices


class CityNameForm(forms.Form):
    """
    CityNameForm Class
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CityNameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['cityName'].choices = cities_as_choices()

    cityName = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=cities_as_choices(),
        help_text="",
        required=False,
        label='Cities',
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some magic changing the `ModelChoiceField.iterator`, however this property is not documented, use at your own risk.

Otherwise, I think you would need to write a custom `ChoiceField`.

```
class ModelChoiceIterator(forms.models.ModelChoiceIterator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.seen = set()

    def __iter__(self):
        for id, label in super().__iter__():
            country = label.split(' ')[0]

            if country not in self.seen:
                yield (id, country)
                self.seen.add(country)

            yield (id, label)


class CityNameChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    iterator = ModelChoiceIterator

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.get_city_name()
```

Comment: I am very well suprised. It was that i thinking to done. Perfect Answer ! i dont think it's needed to write a new `ChoiceField` if the `class ModelChoiceIterator` is not rewrited.